# Display Content between Admin Panel And View Using Laravel Voyager Admin Panel

Tags: laravel, view, controller, admin, voyager

I have installed Laravel Voyager Admin Panel on my Laravel Project which allows me to Update Users' Data at the Admin. At the same Users can also update their profile details on their own individual profiles after they have logged in. This includes uploading profile Photos.

There is no problem with displaying users' account info at both the admin and the view. The Problem is with images. If I change a user's profile image at the Voyager panel, it doesn't show up at the View, at the same time if I use the View to change a user's profile image, it doesn't show up the Voyager Admin Panel.
I'm sure it has to do with Storage location.

Any help will be good.
Thanks

I have searched the internet for solution, but I couldn't get.